# ZipArchive is not working in sever but working in localhost

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

the code below is working in localhost, but not working in server.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = $_POST['zip_category_name'] . $student_id . ".zip";
$zip->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);
$res = $academicObj->get_files_by_category($_POST['download_files_zip']);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    if (file_exists($row['path'] . $row['file'])) {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($row['doc_name']), file_get_contents($row['path'] . $row['file']));
    }
}
if ($zip->numFiles > 0) {
    echo $zip_name;
}
$zip->close();
```

No issue with write permission
my server PHP Version is 7.2.32.  please help....

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: not showing any error

Comment: try looking into apache error logs, if you cant see an error in direct output.

Answer (score 0):

**the plugin for zip archive was missing. i found it by checking using calss_exist() function. thank you for helping**